# Return All Values that Contain a Specific String using Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have the following setup in Oracle, i.e.:

```
(‘aXYZApple-Au’, ‘aXYZOrange-Au’,’aXYZApple-Readonly’,’aXYZOrange-Write’, ’aXYZApple-Write’, ’aXYZOrange-Read’)
```

What I am after is a means of returning only the values that have the word ‘Orange’ from this list.

So if I had a query like:

```
select the_value
from dual
where ‘Orange’ in (‘aXYZApple-Au’, ‘aXYZOrange-Au’,’aXYZApple-Readonly’,’aXYZOrange-Write’, ’aXYZApple-Write’, ’aXYZOrange-Read’)
```

So the above would return only the following as it contains the string ‘Orange’

```
aXYZOrange-Au
aXYZOrange-Write
aXYZOrange-Read
```

Unsure if I have to use regexp_substr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the LIKE operator

```
select the_value
from table1
where the_value like ‘%Orange%’
```

Comment: Thanks Amit - didn't realise that it would be that simple.